# display a success message after file upload using dropzone

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

using the success event I want to display a text to inform the user that the upload is complete!
here's the code

```
 this.on("success", function (file, response) {

   console.log(response.message);
 document.getElementById("maDiv").innerHTML = "success !");
                           });
```

I only get the console message, any suggestions ?

Comment: Do a console.log on `document.getElementById("maDiv")` and `document.getElementById("maDiv").innerHTML` to make sure you're accessing what you expect.

Comment: yes ,it all works.but I still can't display the text on the web page

Answer (score 0):

You have to:

**1.** first of all remove the parenthesis before the semi-colon in `= "success !");`

**2.** check if `#maDiv` is spelled correctly and if your js file or inline script is loaded in your html file correctly.

Comment: the js file is loaded correctly, because when I use; alert(document.getElementById("maDiv").innerHTML = "success !"); it works!!

Comment: @Lamia can you provide a jsfiddle with the whole code? or at list with a portion of the relevant html

Comment: here's the html code on the view :  <div id="maDiv"></div>

Comment: the js file  (dropzone.js) :                                                                                                       this.on("success", function (file, response) {
                       
                        
                      console.log(response.message);
                      console.log(document.getElementById("maDiv"));
                      console.log(document.getElementById("maDiv").innerHTML = "success !");

                    });

Comment: @Lamia the code looks very confused. If I understood correctly you have an ajax request which you are referencing with `this`. You are listening to the success event after the ajax request is completed correctly and then you need to `success!` text inside the `#maDiv` div, is this correct? Are you using jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

You've got a typo on the line that you want to set the success message on. There's a ) which doesn't close anything.